# Vue CLI project not reading vue.config.js

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, config, vue-cli

I am trying to create some aliases to make my package cleaner but my project is ignoring my vue.config.js file. I am using the Vue CLI with Vue v^2.6.11.

vue.config.js:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@vue-toggle-component': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components')
      }
    }
  }
}
```

package.json:

````
{
  "name": "vue-toggle-component",
  "version": "0.1.1",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.4",
    "vue": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ],
  "description": "## Project setup ``` yarn install ```",
  "main": "babel.config.js",
  "repository": "git+https://github.com/nehlis/vue-toggle-component.git",
  "keywords": [
    "Vue.js",
    "Toggle",
    "Component",
    "Lightweight",
    "Checkbox"
  ],
  "author": "Niels Bosman",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/nehlis/vue-toggle-component/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/nehlis/vue-toggle-component#readme"
}
````

When I look online for a solution every page says Vue should read the config file. But it does not, since I tried console logging there and it had no output. Anyone knows more about this?

Comment: Make sure `vue.config.js` is in the root of your project.

Comment: I experience this when running vue-cli-service test:unit.